# How do I calculate this points?

Tags: python, opencv

I have following for loop to extract bounding boxes in an image. Assuming the p is the center point of each box.

Answer (score 3):

The distance formula is: √[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²]. This works for any two points in 2D space with coordinates (x₁, y₁) for the first point and (x₂, y₂) for the second point. You can notice that it is Pythagoras theorem and the distance is the hypotenuse, and the lengths of the sides are the difference between the x and y components of the points.

So once you have p (center  point of bounding box) for two boxes you need to just apply the formula. You can also create a loop and do that for all the p variables that you calculate depending on how many boxes you have.